# How to create a Java instance of the object from Kotlin data class but don't include all fields?

Tags: java, kotlin, dto, data-class

I have the following Kotlin data class:

```
data class Filter @JvmOverloads constructor(
        val key: String? = null,
        val operation: String? = null,
        val value: String? = null,
        val group: String? = null,
        val searchInTranslations: Boolean? = null)
```

I create an instance of this class in Java code. But I want to create an instance with all the fields except for the `group` field. How can I do it in Java?

I can't assign a default value to `group` because in some Java classes I do assign a value to this field, in other Java classes I need to omit this field from object creation.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't support this, but you can make a simple trick.

Generate two constructors, one with the optional field `group`, one without it.
So from the classes you don't need to assign a value to that field, simply make a call to the second constructor:

```
public YourClass(String key, String operation, String value, bool search) 
{
  this (key, operation, value, null, search); //null for the groups
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That would work if the `group` field is the only field that might be needed or not. In case if next time I wouldn't need to include `value` field - I would need to create another constructor. I was thinking of maybe there's a common solution to this approach.

Comment: Oh, I get your point. I think you could do it using some type of factory mechanism that chooses the right constructor. Anyway, did you think about not creating constructor (thus leaving just the default one), and just initializing the fields with setters?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of setting values with setters, but I liked the data class implementation in Kotlin, so started to use it this way. Do you suggest to use a regular class (not data class) and define setters and getters?

Comment: If you don't really have a fixed structure (like, for example, A types never get groups and B types never get operations), you could easily make a constructor factory with your different(fixed) number of constructors. But if you don't really know the exact data types that are incoming, I believe that the setter approach would fit better. Anyway, this is just a philosophical question : )